# Como saber o dia da semana em R?

Tags: r

Existe algum pacote ou função em R que permita obter de maneira fácil o dia da semana a partir de datas?

```
datas <- c("2010-06-28", "2011-05-25", "2010-09-28", "2011-12-05", "2010-09-14", 
           "2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", "2010-01-04", "2010-01-04", 
           "2010-01-04", "2010-01-05", "2010-01-05", "2010-01-05", "2010-01-07", 
           )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para formatar datas em geral você pode usar a função `format()`. As funções `weekdays()` e `months()`, por exemplo, no fundo são wrappers para `format()`.

Para extrair o dia da semana você vai pedir `%a` ou `%A`, a depender se você quiser o dia da semana abreviado ou não:

```
datas <- c("2010-06-28", "2011-05-25", "2010-09-28", "2011-12-05", "2010-09-14", 
           "2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", "2010-01-04", "2010-01-04", 
           "2010-01-04", "2010-01-05", "2010-01-05", "2010-01-05", "2010-01-07") 

format.Date(as.Date(datas), "%a") # abreviado
[1] "seg" "qua" "ter" "seg" "ter" "sex" "sáb" "dom" "seg" "seg" "seg" "ter" "ter" "ter" "qui"

format.Date(as.Date(datas), "%A") 
 [1] "segunda-feira" "quarta-feira"  "terça-feira"   "segunda-feira" "terça-feira"  
 [6] "sexta-feira"   "sábado"        "domingo"       "segunda-feira" "segunda-feira"
[11] "segunda-feira" "terça-feira"   "terça-feira"   "terça-feira"   "quinta-feira"
```

As duas funções são equivalentes a:

```
weekdays(as.Date(datas), abbreviate = TRUE)
weekdays(as.Date(datas))
```

Coloquei o format pois se você quiser pegar mais coisas além do dia da semana é mais fácil. Por exemplo:

```
format.Date(as.Date(datas), "%a, %d de %B de %Y")
 [1] "seg, 28 de junho de 2010"    "qua, 25 de maio de 2011"     "ter, 28 de setembro de 2010"
 [4] "seg, 05 de dezembro de 2011" "ter, 14 de setembro de 2010" "sex, 01 de janeiro de 2010" 
 [7] "sáb, 02 de janeiro de 2010"  "dom, 03 de janeiro de 2010"  "seg, 04 de janeiro de 2010" 
[10] "seg, 04 de janeiro de 2010"  "seg, 04 de janeiro de 2010"  "ter, 05 de janeiro de 2010" 
[13] "ter, 05 de janeiro de 2010"  "ter, 05 de janeiro de 2010"  "qui, 07 de janeiro de 2010"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df = data.frame(date=c("2012-02-01", "2012-02-01", "2012-02-02")) 
df$day <- weekdays(as.Date(df$date))
df

##      data       dia
## 1 2012-02-01   Quarta
## 2 2012-02-01   Quarta
## 3 2012-02-02   Quinta
```

Comment: Ofereça um pouco mais de detalhes ao Autor da Pergunta, assim a resposta servira para pesquisas futuras!